# Delphi: CMD Command is executed but dumpfile is empty

Tags: sql, batch-file, delphi, cmd

I want to make a dump from an sql table.
Here is my code:

**bat-file**

```
cd C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.1/bin
mysqldump -h %1 -u%2 %3 sqlfile > C:/Users/User1/Desktop/sqlfile.sql
```

**delphi code**

```
cmdCommand := Format('cmd.exe /c "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/sqlfile.bat %s %s %s"', [lbl1.Caption, lbl2.Caption, lbl3.Caption]);
ShellExecute(Application.handle, 'open', 'cmd.exe',
PChar(cmdCommand), nil, SW_SHOW);
```

The sql dile is created on the desktop but the file is empty.
Why is the file empty?

When I run the bat file the mysqldump command are not executed. But the commands executed, when I type them manually in the console

Comment: cmdCommand should be only the parameters, not including `cmd.exe`, I think. Having that might have weird side effects.

Comment: Have you tried to run the batch script separately? Also, have you tried outputting %1, %2 and %3 (maybe to a separate file) to see if they contain what you expect?

Comment: %1, %2 and %3 outputs what I expect

Comment: Wouldn't CreateProcess be a better choice here?

Comment: @Keith Miller I think the problem is the bat file. When I execute the bat file, mysqldump is not executed.

Comment: I think the spaces in `cd C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.1/bin` are a problem. Try `cd "C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.1/bin"`

Comment: I thought it was the spaces in the folder names as well, but `cd` apparently doesn't care and also works without quotes. Nevertheless, I'd make sure to test the batch script on its own first. Until that is verified to work, this is not a delphi question, and neither an SQL question, by the way. So check what mysql command you're actually executing, check that by itself, when working on the command line, go back to the batch file, and only then go back to the Delphi program. You're making it really hard for yourself if you're testing this through all 3 layers.

Comment: The way you're doing things now, `ShellExecute` is attempting to run `cmd.exe cmd.exe /c C:/Users/User1/Desktop/sqlfile.bat`. Does that look correct to you? With `cmd.exe cmd.exe /c` starting things?

Comment: @coder007: How do you execute the **bat-file** from the command line and what is the output on the command line?

Comment: Try this: `cmdCommand := Format('/c "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/sqlfile.bat" "%s" "%s" "%s"', [lbl1.Caption, lbl2.Caption, lbl3.Caption]); ShellExecute(Application.Handle, nil, 'cmd.exe', PChar(cmdCommand), nil, SW_SHOW);`